# Помогите решить проблему с margin в css

Tags: html, css, margin

Не могу до конца переместить объект, он как будто упирается в другой. Вот сам код html и css

```css
a{
 color:#ff00cc;
 font-size:32px;
}
#pink{
 color:#ff00cc;
 font-size:32px;
}
#black{
 color:#ff00cc;
 margin-left:900px;
}
#logo{
 margin-left:1150px;
 margin-top:-500px;
 border-radius:30px;
 }
#ap{
 color:#ff00cc;
 font-size:110px;
 margin-top:5px;
 margin-left:650px;
}
body{
 background-color:black;
}
#shap{background-color:#1d1d1d;
 height:20px;
 border-radius:30px;
 width;60px;
 height:110px;
 padding:30px;
 

}
#titlelg{
 margin-left:390px;
}
#str{
 margin-top:50px;
 margin-left:1250px;
}
#poisks{
 margin-top:50px;
}
#mains{
 margin-left:80px;
 margin-bottom:30px;
 
}
#gallery{
 margin-left:110px;
 margin-bottom:30px;
}
#movies{
 margin-left:130px;
 margin-bottom:30px;
}
.button:hover{
 box-shadow:1px 7px 7px #ff00fc;
}
#Block1{
 height:20px;
 border-radius:30px;
 width:700px;
 height:1500px;
 margin-left:1200px;
 margin-top:-826px;
}
#vidos{
 margin-right:10px;
}
#frame1{
 margin-left:1330px;
 margin-top:600px;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
 <head>
  <div>
  <img id="titlelg"src="images/title.png"widht="70" height="70"/>
  </div>
  <div id=shap>
  <a href="test.html"><img id="shaplg"src="images/logo.png" widht="130" height="130"/></a>
  <a href="test.html"><img id="mains"class="button"src="images/main.png" widht="32" height="32"/></a>
  <a href="test.html"><img id="gallery"class="button"src="images/gallery.png" widht="33" height="33"/></a>
  <a href="page1.html"><img id="movies"class="button"src="images/movies.png" widht="35" height="35"/></a>
  </div>
  <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
  <title>
  Home</title>
  <img src=""/>
  <link href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
 </head>
  <body>
   <div id="videohos">
   <div>
   <video id="vidos" width="1170" height="560" controls="controls" autoplay>
   <source src="video/LMV.mp4                                          " type='video/mp4; codecs="avc1.42E01E, mp4a.40.2"'>
   </div>
   </div>
   <div><a id="frame1"href="page2.html"><img id="prv"src="images/preview.png"widht="250" height="250"/></a></div>
   <div id="Block1"style="background: #1d1d1d ;">Block1</div>
   
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

В подобном случае, лучше всего присылать ссылку на какую-нибудь песочницу, где проект можно посмотреть вживую. Например, на codepen.
У Вас в коде такие margin указаны, что они сдвинут элемент на весь экран. Вот этот блок размером 700px в ширину и высотой в 1500px с левым margin 1200px уедет с любого монитора за его пределы.

```
`#Block1{
    height:20px;
    border-radius:30px;
    width:700px;
    height:1500px;
    margin-left:1200px;
    margin-top:-826px;
}`
```

Comment: Вот сайт на песочнице https://codepen.io/Farlock/pen/BaopyPj